# Calculate the formation energy of a cannister

Tags: density-functional-theory, formation-energy

I have calculated the energies of a substance in a cylindrical canister using DFT, with an oxygen vacancy, with an oxygen interstitial and purely stoichiometric. I am struggling to figure out how to determine the formation energy, relating the oxygen in the headspace of the canister to the defects. I believe I can use the chemical potential, but I'm not really too familiar with chemistry...

Please let me know what you suggest.

Thank you :)